# different value for decode in c# and python

Tags: python, c#, base64, encode, password-hash

I want to get the same Value (PasswordHash) in Python like when I got it in bytes in C#

C# code:

```cs
byte [] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEAco3n3jFZc+9/IXf5IFpCnLz7Yx/c8lAw+cZ3JvFcWA8xL1Oa90gX/yzB6h6KsUgg==");
Text = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
//output is 010000000100002710000000100728DE7DE315973EF7F2177F9205A429CBCFB631FDCF25030F9C67726F15C580F312F539AF74817FF2CC1EA1E8AB1482
```

Python code:

```
x="AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEAco3n3jFZc+9/IXf5IFpCnLz7Yx/c8lAw+cZ3JvFcWA8xL1Oa90gX/yzB6h6KsUgg=="
x_bytes = base64.b64decode(x)
y=str(x_bytes)[2:]
print(y.replace('\\x',''))
#output is 01000000010000'100000001007(de}e31597>f7f2177f9205a4)cbcfb61fdcf%030f9cgro15c580f312f59aft817ff2cc1ea1e8ab1482"
```

Can you please explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both produce the same sequence of bytes:

> 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 27 10 00 00 00 10 07 28 DE
> 7D E3 15 97 3E F7 F2 17 7F 92 05 A4 29 CB CF B6
> 31 FD CF 25 03 0F 9C 67 72 6F 15 C5 80 F3 12 F5
> 39 AF 74 81 7F F2 CC 1E A1 E8 AB 14 82

You just treat them differently after decoding them.

Looks like you want the hex of the bytes. All you need is

```py
bytes.hex()
```

```
>>> import base64
>>> b64 = "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEAco3n3jFZc+9/IXf5IFpCnLz7Yx/c8lAw+cZ3JvFcWA8xL1Oa90gX/yzB6h6KsUgg=="
>>> bytes = base64.b64decode(b64)
>>> bytes.hex()
'010000000100002710000000100728de7de315973ef7f2177f9205a429cbcfb631fdcf25030f9c67726f15c580f312f539af74817ff2cc1ea1e8ab1482'
```

Comment: I need to have python Output same like C# but i don't know how

Comment: Added. . . . . . .